# Output XML as file in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm having difficulty sending an XML stream to the client browser. I've researched this considerably and everything looks right - moreover, similar code works in a previous version of this app. Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

The following code throws no errors, but does not download a file on the client machine.

```
        Public Shared Sub Export(ByVal source As DataTable)

        Try

            With Current.Response


                Dim xml As String = CreateExcelXMLFromDataTable(source.DefaultView)

                .Clear()
                .Buffer = True
                .ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
                .AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Concat("attachment;filename=", "export.xlsx", ";"))
                .AddHeader("Content-Length", xml.Length.ToString)
                .Charset = ""
                .Write(xml)
                .Flush()
                .Close()

            End With


        Catch ex As Exception

            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString)

        End Try

    End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: What indication do you have that it's wrong?  Is there an error message?  Unexpected output?

Comment: No error message at all. Just nothing, when I would otherwise expect a file to download or a download dialog box to pop up.

Comment: Are you sure the code is executing at all then?  When you debug this, what happens?  Note that outside of a debugger you're *ignoring* any and all errors from this code.  What exactly do you expect `Console.WriteLine` to do in a web application?  So there very well could be an error, you're just explicitly ignoring it.

Comment: Yes, I can step through the code all the way to the end. It's definitely executing, and I can see that the xml variable is definitely getting populated with text. Console.writeline is just there for debugging/development purposes.

Comment: What happens if you put `.End()` after `.Close()` ?

Comment: I did try that as well. It has no effect. I've also tried HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest().

Comment: Not sure if this makes a difference, but I should mention that I'm making this request via AJAX - no postback occurs. Now that I think of it, is that even possible, or would I have trigger the download as part of a page request?

Comment: Definetely full postback is required for file download.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling this function in an Ajax request it will not work. You have to cause a full postback to send the file to the client.

You can send the file without causing a full postback in the current page using an popup window (`window.open`) or an `iframe` with the URL of the download asp.net page, which will call the `Export` function.

Comment: Here's a nice little article on how to make that work. Thanks for the help, folks.  http://encosia.com/ajax-file-downloads-and-iframes/